# If I remove my SIM card from my iPhone, will iMessage still be connected to my phone number, or can I only be reached by my Apple ID email?

Tags: iphone, apple-id, messages, sim, internationalization

I'm traveling internationally and I'm removing my SIM card. Even if I don't have my phone number connected to my iPhone by the SIM card, will it still be connected to iMessage for people to contact me through? Should I tell them to text my Apple ID email(s)? Or well I still be able to receive the messages if they text my phone number?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an iPhone myself, but because the account can be based on email address as well, I believe it in theory should be possible to keep using iMessage after removing your sim. *However*, I have experienced that my friends who have gone overseas and *used a different sim* have ended up having iMessage being connected to the *new* number. In other words, it is possible to connect to you via iMessage, but your new, overseas number will need to be made known.